# If I Want To Build An Addon to GMail, Do I Need To Store Plaintext Passwords?

Tags: security, passwords, gmail, imap

From what I understand about POP/IMAP, I need the user's plaintext password to be able to retrieve email on their behalf. If I wanted to create an addon service to GMail that access their mail through the POP/IMAP servers, do I pretty much have to save their plaintext password? Is there anything I can do to get around this? If I have to save a plaintext password, what's the best way to do it?

EDIT: Actually it looks like GMail supports OAuth authentication for their IMAP/SMTP servers: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_overview

Not exactly sure how OAuth works with IMAP and SMTP, but it's a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're writing it in (PHP, JS, etc.), but this is [Gmailr](http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/02/05/introducing-gmailr-an-unofficial-javscript-api-for-gmail/), a Javascript API for Gmail.

In addition, look at [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/oauth_libraries) which provides a guide to using Oauth with IMAP and SMTP in Java, Python, and PHP.